# return table except deleted_at (softdeletes) laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to return a table without deleted rows (softdeletes)

This is my code

```
public function getMailRecipients($meoId){
    return DB::table('mail_recipients')->where('meo_id', '=', $meoId)->select('name', 'email')->get();
}
```

but I get all rows, even those removed through softdeletes, What else should I add to avoid that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using query builder (facade DB) in this case you should do this:

```
DB::table('mail_recipients')->where('meo_id', '=', $ meoId)->whereNull('deleted_at')->select('name', 'email')->get();
```

If you use the model, you must use the SoftDeletes trait

```
class Flight extends Model{
 use SoftDeletes;
}
```

see more in the documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#soft-deleting

Comment: oh, ok, you're right, I did it with the models and it works, but with your method too, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Note *: The soft deleting feature works when using Eloquent. If you are querying the results with query builder you will eventually see all the records trashed and not trashed.

You can try with this:

```
public function getMailRecipients($meoId)
{
    return DB::table('mail_recipients')
          ->whereNull('deleted_at')
          ->where('meo_id', $meoId)
          ->get(['name', 'email']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you arrived here because you are using `protected $softDelete = true` in your model and Laravel seems to ignore it, the solution is to `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes` in your model. Works everytime!